# Dockerfile vs Dockerrun.aws.json on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

Can anyone explain use cases for using either or both of these in an EB project? I understand from the docs that using one makes the other optional, but I'm not exactly clear on pros vs cons. Any good scenarios for using both? For my EB app, I'm building a Docker Image manually through a Dockerfile (not a repo) and launching a node.js server.

Comment: Speculating that the tradeoff is (1) Dockerfile is simpler to get working with because you don't need to setup a Docker Image registry and (2) Dockerrun.aws.json is more performant (faster to deploy) because you don't need to rebuild from scratch every single time